# TensorFlow 1.2 How to Setup Time Series Prediction at Inference Time Using Seq2Seq

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to study the tf.contrib.seq2seq section of the TensorFlow library using a toy model. Currently, my graph is as follows:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Placeholders
enc_inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_input])
expect = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_output])
expect_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])

# Encoder
cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden), output_keep_prob=keep_prob) for i in range(layers_stacked_count)]
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
encoded_outputs, encoded_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, enc_inp, dtype=tf.float32)

# Decoder
de_cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden), output_keep_prob=keep_prob) for i in range(layers_stacked_count)]
de_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(de_cells)

training_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(expect, expect_length)

decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=de_cell, helper=training_helper, initial_state=encoded_states)
final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder)

decoder_logits = final_outputs.rnn_output

h = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(decoder_logits, n_output)

diff = tf.squared_difference(h, expect)
batch_loss = tf.reduce_sum(diff, axis=1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(batch_loss)

optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
training_op = optimiser.minimize(loss)
```

The graph trains very well and executes fine. However, I am not sure what to do at inference time, since this graph always requires the `expect` variable (the value which I am trying to predict).

As I understand, the TrainingHelper function is using the ground truth as input, so what I need is another helper function at inference time.

Most implementations of seq2seq model I've seem appears to be outdated (tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq). Some of the most up-to-date models often use GreddyEmbeddingHelper, which I'm not sure is appropriate for continuous time series predictions.

Another possible solution I've found is to use the CustomHelper function. However, there is no little material out there for me to learn and I've just kept banging my head against the wall.

**If I am trying to implement a seq2seq model for time series prediction, what should I do at inference time?**

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly that part "Another possible solution I've found is to use the CustomHelper function. However, there is no little material out there for me to learn and I've just kept banging my head against the wall." is missing and samples are needed

Comment: Have you managed to solve this using as CustomHelper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you need to use another helper function for inference, but you need to share weights between testing and inference.

You can do this with tf.variable_scope()

```
with tf.variable_scope("decode"):
    training_helper = ...

with tf.variable_scope("decode", reuse = True):
    inference_helper = ...
```

For a more complete example, see one of these two examples:

- https://github.com/pplantinga/tensorflow-examples/blob/master/TensorFlow%201.2%20seq2seq%20example.ipynb
- https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/seq2seq/sequence_to_sequence_implementation.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I been looking for!

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Have you used the InferenceHelper to solve this?

Comment: @MrfksIV did you find a way to use inferenceHelper?