# Provide Tensorflow Seq2Seq output as input at next step (inference)

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, seq2seq

I would like to create a Seq2Seq model to forecast time series data. I am using the InferenceHelper and I am struggling with the `sample_fn` parameter. I would like to pass the decoder output of each cell through a dense layer in order to generate a single output at each time step. So I'm providing a function that does this to the `sample_fn` parameter.

Later on I would like to concatenate the rnn cell outputs with other non-time-series features and build more dense layers on top of it.

The network does fine at training time but not during inference. I think this is caused by the fact that I'm not sharing the same dense layer between training and inference time.

I tried to set the reuse parameter and used a `with tf.variable_scope()` environment. However, the `sample_fn` is already called within a specific scope in `dynamic_decode` and so I fail to use the same scope as I did during training.

The relevant part of my code looks as follows:

The placeholders:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
input_lengths = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_lengths')

targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.float32, name='targets')
target_lengths = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='target_lengths')
```

The encoder:

```
encoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units=16, name='encoder_cell_0'])
self.decoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units=16, name='decoder_cell_0']))

_, final_encoder_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=encoder_cell, inputs=inputs,
                                                sequence_length=input_lengths, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The decoder (training)

```
start_tokens = tf.fill([tf.shape(inputs)[0]], start_token)
start_tokens = tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(start_tokens, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
targets_as_inputs = tf.concat([start_tokens, targets], axis=1)
targets_as_inputs = tf.reshape(targets_as_inputs, (-1, targets_as_inputs.shape[1], 1))

training_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs=targets_as_inputs, sequence_length=target_lengths, name='training_helper')
training_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=decoder_cell, helper=training_helper, initial_state=final_encoder_states)

train_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=training_decoder, maximum_iterations=max_target_sequence_length, impute_finished=True)

train_predictions = train_outputs.rnn_output
train_predictions = tf.layers.dense(train_predictions, 1, activation=None, name='output_dense_layer')
```

The decoder (inference). The incorrect part:

```
def sample_fn(outputs):
    return tf.layers.dense(outputs, 1, activation=None,         
                           name='output_dense_layer', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

infer_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.InferenceHelper(sample_fn=sample_fn, sample_shape=(1), 
                                                       sample_dtype=tf.float32, start_inputs=start_tokens, end_fn=lambda sample_ids: False, next_inputs_fn=None)
infer_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=decoder_cell, helper=infer_helper, initial_state=final_encoder_states)

infer_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=infer_decoder, maximum_iterations=max_target_sequence_length, impute_finished=True)

infer_predictions = infer_outputs.rnn_output
infer_predictions = sample_fn(infer_predictions)
```

There is a similar question: [How to use tensorflow seq2seq without embeddings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134432/how-to-use-tensorflow-seq2seq-without-embeddings)

The author uses `sample_fn=lambda outputs: outputs`. But this returns a ValueError in my case because the dimensions don't match. How could they with multiple cells? `sample_fn` should return a single value.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have solved my problem by creating my own dynamic_decode function. I copied everything beside

```
with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope, "decoder", reuse=reuse) as varscope:
```

as well as a related if condition with `varscope` and another if condition testing the decoder class from `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode`.

Not a nice solution but good enough for now.